# Want to integrate one-one and one-many (Group Chat) in React Native (Expo Managed)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, managed

I have an idea about one-one integration using gifted chat but I also want to integrate Group Chat. How can I achieve this functionality. I have integrated one-one but now I want to add create group functionality and then chat between users in the specific group.

Thanks

Want to integrate Group Chat using Gifted Chat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.